# Solving IVP with delta function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the IVP. $y^{''}+2y^{'}+2y=\delta(t-\pi); \;\;y(0)=1\;\;y^{'}(0)=0$

Here is what I did: I took the Laplace transform of the IVP and obtained the following $$(s^2+2s+2)Y[S]-s-1=e^{-\pi s}$$ Solving for $Y[S]$ yields $$\dfrac{e^{-\pi s}+s+1}{s^2+2s+2}=\dfrac{e^{-\pi s}}{(s+1)^2+1}+\dfrac{s+1}{(s+1)^2+1}$$ The inverse LaPlace Transform of this function is simply $$u_{\pi}(t)e^{-(t-\pi)}\sin(t-\pi)+e^{-t}\cos(t)$$ according to the book I am missing a $+e^{-t}\sin (t)$  can anyone point out any errors I have made in my calculations?

Comment: I found my mistake. I forgot to multiply $y(0)$ by 2 thus leading to $s+2$ on the top which accounts for the $e^{-t}sin(t)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation of the Laplace transform of the left hand side isn't quite correct; you should have

$$(s^2 Y(s) - s) + 2(s Y(s) - 1) + 2 Y(s) = Y(s) (s^2 + 2s + 2) - s - 2$$

Thus,

$$Y(s) = \frac{e^{-\pi s}}{(s + 1)^2 + 1} + \frac{s + 1}{(s + 1)^2 + 1} + \frac{1}{(s + 1)^2 + 1}$$

which gives exactly the $e^{-t} \sin t$ term you were looking for.

Comment: yes I just noticed that I need to be more careful with these transforms.